# how to maximize a linear function subject to a unit L2 norm constraint

Tags: optimization

I have a very simple problem.  For a vector $x$ and cost vector $c$, I want to maximize $c.x$ subject to the constraint that $\|x\| = 1$, meaning that the $L_2$ norm of $x$ should be 1.

I have found this paper:

on gradient adaptation with unit-norm constraints
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.38.8334&rep=rep1&type=pdf

However that is for the slightly more general problem of $\max f(x)$ s.t. $\|x\| = 1$ for a nonlinear objective $f(x)$.

I was wondering if there was a specific solution for the linear objective. Obviously I can use the more general technique if need be.

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you are interested in is $$\max_{x:\|x\| = 1} c^\top x.$$ The best $x$ would the one that is pointing in the same direction as $c$. This along with the fact that it is of unit norm, yields $x^* = c/\|c\|$ and $c^\top x^* = \|c\|$. You can verify the correctness using cauchy-schwartz inequality.

Comment: Cauchy-schwarz is all you need to prove it